# Closing a database connection in Java

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, connection

I have the following method in my database class that returns a resultset for a given SQL statement:

```
public static ResultSet sqlStatement(String query) throws SQLException{
    ResultSet result = null; 
    Connection conn = connect();
    Statement newStatement = conn.createStatement(); 
    result = newStatement.executeQuery(query);
    conn.close();
    return result;
}
```

I want to close the connection to the database before i return the resultset but it throws the following exception:

```
java.sql.SQLException: out of memory
```

I'm a java noob and experimenting so any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Increase your memory via the -Xmx startup parameter, or don't return as many rows--do you know how many your query returns?

Comment: What database are you using? And can you post your query please? It looks as though it's the database itself that ran out of memory

Comment: Its a table with about 4 columns and 3 rows, the statment is "SELECT * FROM table". I'm pretty sure thats not causing memory problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my past experience(No document or anything), I would understand the "ResultSet" like a pointer in C. I bet it would cache some rows from database when you execute your query..

Therefore, if you close connection and then try to use resultset, all those cached resultset does not have proper information and getting next cache etc. As a result, it would throw out of memory exception..

Anyway proper way to use those in java..

```
Connection con...
try{
    create connection
    execute query
    use your resultset completely..
}catch(...){
}finally{
    close connection;
}
```

Hope it would help

Comment: great thanks for the help, I think I'll have to create an ArrayList in the method and return this. Not sure how to maintain table structure...

Answer (score 1):

Put the `conn.close()` in a `finally` block so that it gets executed event if an exception is thrown.

Comment: It's unlikely that this is the reason for the out of memory exception

Answer (score 1):

**always, always, always close your database resources in a finally block!**

i doubt your logic will work as is.  a ResultSet is only usable while the connection is open.  you need to process the entire ResultSet *before* you close the connection.

Comment: From the JavaDoc, it would seem that a ResultSet gets closed if the Statement it resulted from gets closed. This gets mentioned in the doc for the `close()` methods of both ResultSet and Statement. However, there is no such information regarding the closing of a Connection. It might be safe to close a connection as long as the Statement isn't closed.

Comment: Ok. Is there a way to translate the resultset into a java object, preserving the table structure? I guess I could work out a way with arraylist.

Comment: @G_H, no: Closing the connection closes statements opened by that connection and thus also resultsets. It is not mentioned explicitly in the docs, but it does mention on Connection: 'SQL statements are executed and results are returned within the context of a connection' and Connection.close(): 'Releases this Connection object's database and JDBC resources immediately instead of waiting for them to be automatically released'. This implies that the statement is closed as well when closing the connection.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel: I was wondering about that. Having a bit more clarity in the doc would be nice, though. I've seen sites that contradict this and state it is safe to close a connection immediately. Any word on this in the JDBC spec? I'm not entirely certain what would be counted as "database and JDBC resources" outside of a Connection object. Is it possible some implementations create a separate connection for resultsets?

Comment: JDBC 4.0 spec section 9.4.4 states: "All Statement objects created from a given Connection object will be closed when the close method for the object is called." Looks like the connection does indeed need to remain open. Apparently, `Statement` objects are closed on garbage collection (probably via finalize), but it's good practice to close them yourself.

Comment: @G_H Should have looked it up in the spec myself, but I didn't have it at hand on this machine :)

Answer (score 0):

Apart from closing resources in a finally block, you also have to close your `PreparedStatement` and your `ResultSet`. In fact, you shouldn't return the `ResultSet` and keep it open for too long. Instead, you could read it into some sort of intermediary data store, such as a `List<Object[]>`.

On the other hand, you're not getting a `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError`, so possibly it's your database itself that ran out of memory